# Customizing iOS's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method in a Cordova/Ionic project

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm newish to Cordova and am wondering if there is a way to tweak the platform code generated by Cordova/Ionic without hindering the development process.

The specific requirement is to integrate the Facebook SDK to the iOS app in order to support Facebook Mobile App Install ads. Integration is straightforward: it only requires adding a line of code to 
`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in AppDelegate.m and adding the Facebook iOS framework to the Xcode project.

Currently the entire plaforms directory is excluded from source control, as it is generated by Cordova during build. If I am to tweak AppDelegate.m, I will have to add it to source control. Then won't subsequent changes to the Ionic app result in merge conflicts with the Xcode project? How can I integrate my small changes to the Xcode project without breaking the process?

**NOTE:** I did look for a plugin as a solution, but the plugin I found comes [with complications of its own](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/). And it appears that Cordova does not provide hooks in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should create your own plugin instead of making changes into the AppDelegate.m

You can listen the `UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification` on the `pluginInitialize` an put the code there

```
- (void)pluginInitialize
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(finishLaunching:) name:UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)finishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Put here the code that should be on the AppDelegate.m
}
```

The plugin.xml need the onload true to call the pluginInitialize

```
<feature name="yourPluginName">
    <param name="ios-package" value="yourPluginClass" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

Comment: Thank you, I verified this and it works!  In fact it's probably even just as good to place that code inside `pluginInitialize`, as in an Ionic/Cordova app it does end up being called from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` anyway (via the load method of the Cordova view controller which this method triggers after initializing it as root view controller and calling makeKeyAndVisible)

Comment: yes, putting the code inside pluginInitialize should be enough, using the observer is only needed if the app is launched, in example, from a push notification when the app is closed, and you want to get the push notification info from the plugin, or some other cases where application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: received some info and you want that info

Comment: Only when using `onload=true` I got an error any idea? `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SharingReceptor handleApplicationDidFinishLaunching]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb63bc016d0'`

Comment: jcesarmobile I think it's because I need to add `:` after the selector name (but don't know why, I'm not an iOS dev and it's my first cordova plugin attempt...). onload=true seems to be required if I want to receive the startup event too.

Comment: yeah, sorry, you have to put : on the selector because `finishLaunching` is expecting the notification object, if you don't use the notification object on the `finishLaunching` method you could just change it to `- (void)finishLaunching{}` and shouldn't get the error

Comment: thanks jcesarmobile you really helped me out with your answer.

Comment: hey @jcesarmobile thanks for this answer, I think you can help me with a similar question regarding [iOS plugin for cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958904/add-extra-delegate-to-cordova-appdelegate-ios). Can you please take a look? thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

You could use this plugin for that:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-app-event

Answer (score 0):

You can make additions to the app delegate file, that change will not go away unlike files inside www folder. You can make changes inside the Xcode project folder.

Comment: Thanks! But what about the xcodeproj file? I would have to change it too  to add the Facebook framework. I presume this file will also be changed by Cordova if configuration changes are made. Granted, this shouldn't happen too often.