# Passing custom parameters to Phonegap plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have written a Phonegap plugin in order to integrate my Phonegap application with a native SDK library. In order to pass some device registration information to the native library I have used an Objective-C category to plug my own handler after didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, pretty much the same way the [Phonegap Push Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) does. I therefore have something like the following:

```
@implementation AppDelegate (MyLib)

// Using method swizzling to plug our own init method  which allows us to
// add our own listener for the didFinishLaunching event without overwriting
// the one already defined by Phonegap.
+ (void)load
{
    Method original, swizzled;

    original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(init));
    swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(swizzled_init));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}

- (AppDelegate *)swizzled_init
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(launchHandler:)
                                                 name:@"UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification" object:nil];

    // This actually calls the original init method over in AppDelegate.
    return [self swizzled_init];
}

// This code will be called immediately after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.
- (void)launchHandler:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSString* apiKey = @"xxxxx";
    // Do some initialisation and register the device using the apiKey
}

@end
```

The apiKey is specific to my application and right now it is defined in AppDelegate+MyLib.m as shown in the code above. My question is, is there a way to allow my Phonegap app to customise this when importing the plugin? Could it be defined in my app's config.xml (or in any other place if that makes a difference) and somehow passed to the plugin's AppDelegate as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firts of all, you don't need to use swizzling, just read how to get the UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification from a CDVPlugin subclass

[Customizing iOS's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method in a Cordova/Ionic project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000387/customizing-ioss-applicationdidfinishlaunchingwithoptions-method-in-a-cordova/31070821)

Now you can use the preference tag on the config.xml

```
 <preference name="apiKey" value="yourApiKeyHere" />
```

Then, you get the "apiKey" on your code (on a CDVPlugin subclass) doing this:

```
NSString* apiKey = [self.commandDelegate.settings objectForKey:[@"apiKey" lowercaseString]];
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I get the following error when attempting to retrieve the key in my code:
Property 'commandDelegate' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

Comment: Ok, this code will only work on a CDVPlugin subclass, as you are swizzling the AppDelegate it won't work there, I'll update the answer so you don't use swizzling

Comment: After this update it worked. I'm also writing down some extra configuration I had to do for future reference. Feel free to add them to your answer to make it more complete:
1. I used <param name="onload" value="true"/> in the feature I defined in my plugin.xml in order for the pluginInitialize method to be executed.
2. I used a variable for the api key in my plugin.xml, which means in the feature I have <preference name="apiKey" value="$API_KEY"/> and right under the platform definition <preference name="API_KEY"/>

Comment: 3. I specified the api key as a variable when adding the plugin in my app's config.xml:
<plugin name="myplugin" spec="https://my-repository.git">
        <variable name="API_KEY" value="xxxxx" />
    </plugin>

Comment: the preference with the key should be enough, the variables are used when you pass the variable on plugin install instead of setting the key on the config.xml