# Add extra delegate to Cordova AppDelegate iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am building a plugin to integrate an external framework to an Cordova, following the documentation, I need to include a new delegate to `AppDelegate.h` of my app.

If was developing a native application, i just need to import the file and include the delegate on it.

```
#import <MySpinServerSDK/MySpinServerSDK.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, MySpinServerSDKDelegate>
```

How can I add a extra delegate to a Cordova App for iOS using the plugin structure?

I did all the preparation in a plugin (external frameworks an plist configuration) but not sure if its possible to create this kind of integration using cordova plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference these Cordova Plugins as examples: [App-Event](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-app-event) or [Deep Links](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin)

Note how the App Event developer named the new files with a plus sign: AppDelegate+APPAppEvent.h and AppDelegate+APPAppEvent.m in his Cordova plugin. In the header file, the developer used a category "APPAppEvent" while declaring his new class as an AppDelegate:

```
@interface AppDelegate (APPAppEvent)

@end
```

The Deep Links developer did the same:

```
@interface AppDelegate (CULPlugin)

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler;

@end
```

Comment: thanks you for the answer... the App-Event plugin helped a lot... =)